# Running C++ program on other machines

Tags: windows, dll, installation

So I know it is a common question. I want to be able to run C++ programs on other Windows machines without installing Visual Studio on them. Naturally, I get the error message about a missing dll file. I was wondering if I could create an installer to just install that dll and then be able to run the program. Would that work or are there other needed files? If would, how would I do such a thing? It sure would be nice to have an automatic installer. Thanks

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if there is any `static` compile option. There should be. So that you can compile your program statically, what would put all the necessary `dll` files in executable, so that you can move exe file on other windows platform, without install `VS`.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to figure out what DLLs (and controls, etc.) you need is with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly what dll files are missing, you could simply provide them next to your application, in a .zip file for instance.

Making a installer for windows is not an easy task. You might want to look into software that does it for you, such as [Setup Factory](http://www.indigorose.com/products/setup-factory/) (paid) or [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) (free). These software will allow you to create professional looking installations pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that you do not have to install the whole VS to run your app there, but just the VS [redistributable package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) that is probably even smaller (~5 MB) than your statically compiled application? You can also use the [deployment bootstrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4k032e1.aspx) if you want your app including prerequisites to appear to be made of one piece.

However, statical linking is also a good option, especially if your program does not consist of too many binary files and is performing a very simple task.